# io.read('*all') returns nil when trying to read file

Tags: lua

For some reason, this code returns nil

```
file = io.open("file.txt","r+") 
thingfulthink = io.read('*all')
print(thinkfulthing)
```

also if I try to compare that variable (thinkfulthing) an error jumps with the legend: error, can't compare number with 'nil'

Sorry if it's hard to read but I have the whole code in my pc and I'm writing from the phone, I'll edit tomorrow to add the full code

--edit

Also the file looks like this

```
200
```

And I tried using Python to open and read the file and it does return 200 as expected

```
file = open("file.txt", "r,")
thingfulthink = file.read()
print(thinkfulthing)
```

Comment: Note the difference between line 2 in both programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `file:read('*all')` instead of `io.read('*all')`.